# Is it possible to check if the dedicated gpu is active or not + being monitored? (Nvidia Optimus)

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, gpu, optimus

I have a laptop (Msi GV62) with GTX 1050 graphics card and optimus system with it. And my question is, how can I check if optimus is active or not? If my dedicated graphics card is active in any way or not?

I found that I can have an icon in tray, that informs me if dedicated gpu is active or not. But I found that it is not 100% accurate and works with delay. E.g. TechPower GPU-Z uses dedicated graphics card by monitoring it, but icon in tray says that it doesn't run on my dedicated GPU. If I hit many many times refresh in GPU-Z then I can be lucky enough to see for a short moment in tray icon that dedicated gpu is active. But as I say, for a little period of time + doing massive refresh in GPU-Z. Although GPU-Z is constantly monitoring dedicated graphics card, it is active but tray icon says that it isn't

Another example is that Msi Afterburner when is running is making dedicated gpu active almost all time, it looks like ON, OFF, ON, OFF but tray icon doesn't show it, it says GPU is inactive and doesn't even list Msi Afterburner

This cause my dedicated GPU to stay activated and get a little little bit more hot overtime instead of being disabled and staying cold.

Let's say I don't know I have GPU-Z running and it monitors my gpu. How can I tell that there are applications that are monitoring my gpu and what apps they are?

In other words, how can I know what applications are currently monitoring my gpu?

Is there a way to list all programs that are currently monitoring my gpu? Just the way like seeing which apps are running on gpu

If it is possible to have absolutely knowledge of all applications that are currently using or monitoring the dedicated GPU...

---

This tray icon is: https://uk.answers.acer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/9075/~/determining-which-graphics-card-is-used-with-nvidia-optimus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The applications using the GPU can be displayed in Task Manager as follows:

- Sorting by the "GPU Engine" column in descending order shows all the
  applications using the GPU and even their current operation.
- Sorting by the column "GPU" in descending order shows all processes
  using the GPU by their percentage of use.

Other indicators possible are:

- Install [8GadgetPack](https://8gadgetpack.net/)
  to revive the sidebar and install one of the
  [GPU gadgets](http://win7gadgets.com/s?q=gpu)
- Install the free [GPU Temp](http://www.gputemp.com/)
  to show temperature and load.
  This can also be seen in Task Manager in the Performance tab
  (although in less compact form).